# dash update dash_core_components widget value programmatically

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am new to dash and i am not able to find out how to update a widget value without having to create a function and wrap it with a callback and an input from another widget.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

# create radio items widget 
widget=dcc.RadioItems(
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
            {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'MTL'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
        ],
        value='MTL')

# append this to a html.div children.
div  = html.Div([widget])
app.layout = div

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


# normally I would like to be able to update the widget value programmatically and have the html UI updated automatically too
widget.set_value('SF')
```

appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You have already found the Dash answer. Any updates to the UI will come from callbacks. You can have the `Input` value that triggers the callback come from the user interacting with another component, such as clicking on a button, or it can update every x seconds with the `Interval` component, or it can be one in a cascade of updates with each one listening to the one before it, ultimately triggered by, likely, a user interaction.

Comment: Thank you. This is something i know already but I wonder if it's possible to update using a direct method not having to touch the interface.

Comment: It is not possible. Any changes to Dash components have to happen through callbacks.